# La respuesta del servidor se muestra en la consola del navegador pero no en la página

Tags: ajax, alert

Envio los datos al servidor mediante la función ajax y se envian correctamente ya que se almacenan en la BD.Utilizo ARC y la respuesta es la esperada.
Ahora mi problema esta en el cliente.Al recibir el objeto json en el argumento de la función done e imprimirlo mediante un alert, este no imprime el contenido o mensaje.
Prob hacer lo mismo pero con el debugger del navegador y ahi me muestra correctamente el contenido del argumento de la función done. Creo que el error esta en el cliente, pero no lo estoy viendo.
Que esta pasando? Como puedo solucionarlo?
adjunto el código cliente y el código del servidor

código del cliente

```
$(function() {
    $("#botonEnviar").on("click", function () {
        var deporte = localStorage.getItem("deporte");
        var h = $("#hora").val();
        var datosJson = JSON.stringify({
            nombreCliente: $("#nombre").val(),
            apellidoCliente: $("#apellido").val(),
            deporte: deporte,
            fecha: $("#fecha").val(),
            hora: parseInt(h,10),
            cod:20
        });
        //alert(datosJson);
        localStorage.removeItem('deporte');
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/LA_GLORIA1/rest/restfull.php',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            data: datosJson,
            processData: false}).
            done(function(data) {
                //$("#divServidor").css("display","block");
                //$("#pServidor").val(data);
                try {
                    var resp= data;
                    alert(resp.mensaje);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }

            }).
            fail(function(){
            }); 
        });
});
```

código del servidor- PHP

```
$datos = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $solicitud = json_decode($datos, true);
        $cod1 = $solicitud['cod'];
        $nom = $solicitud['nombreCliente'];
        $ape = $solicitud['apellidoCliente'];
        $deport = $solicitud['deporte'];
        $fecha = $solicitud['fecha'];
        $hora = $solicitud['hora'];
        $insert = new Consultas();
        $mensaje = $insert->insertar($cod1, $nom, $ape, $deport, $fecha, $hora); //$solicitud['deporte']);
        //$mensaje1 = utf8_encode($mensaje);
        $m = utf8_encode($mensaje);
        //header('Content-type: application/json');
        //echo json_encode($mensaje1);
        $a = array("mensaje" => $m);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($a);
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor pasa lo que anotaste como respuesta al final de esta pregunta. La autorrespuesta es válida cuando resuelve la duda de modo efectivo.

Answer (score 0):

Nose porque pero cambie el `<input type="submit"/>` por `<input type="button"/>` y me funciona perfecto. Se muestra el mensaje de la BD. Miro en la BD y los datos del formularia se almacenan correctamente.
Busque la diferencia entre estos dos tipos y uno se usa para enviar formularios(submit) el otro se usa para cambiar el color de un elemento por ejemplo.
Ahora alguien me puede explicar por favor ¿Porque me funciono con el tipo buton y no con el tipo submit por favor?

Comment: Con el tipo `submit`, ¿notabas que se te refrescara la página por completo? Eso podría explicar que no se te mostrara la respuesta.

Comment: si exacto. Y que cuando abria la consola me mostraba lo que tenia en la funcion done pero salia de la consola y no me mostraba el alert.

Comment: Entonces es eso, el tipo `submit` hace refresco de la página cuando envías el formulario. Para evitarlo puedes usar `e.preventDefault()` dentro de tu función `click` pasándole un parámetro `e`.